# Python libs for text segmentation

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, cluster-computing, semantics

Could anybody suggest good method and/or libs for text segmentation?

E.g. I have a set of bigrams or trigrams. ANd then I want to say, that these bigrams refers to one cluster, those to that cluster and so on.

After I clusterized, I will manually name these clusters.

I need to create smth like a dictionary to classify text comments into categories ('complains', 'spam' and so on)...

____ edited____

I have stopped my search with gensim lib and LDA modelling. It works quite good

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I have seen a lot of questions on nltk. Which might mean it's popular, or it might mean it's hard to use. ;-)

Comment: Yeah, question is quite general, but my problem is to find a good algo. I can;t specify it more precisely at the moment

Answer (score 0):

[nltk](http://www.nltk.org/), or Natural Language Toolkit is the go-to tool for processing text in Python. This will handle the segmentation aspect of your project.

Specifically, you may be interested in the `tokenize` module! [See the documentation for more details.](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#module-nltk.tokenize)

Comment: Now I am getting in touch with gensim lib. I will check results

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Pawpaw](https://github.com/rlayers/pawpaw), a high performance text segmentation framework for Python that allows you to do complex, deep segmentation of text.  Segments are automatically organized into tree graphs that can be serialized, traversed, and searched using a powerful structured query language.

Pawpaw also features a framework for quickly and easily building complex, pipelined parsers.